# How do I capture keystroke events in D3 force layout?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I would like to respond to keystroke events directed at nodes in my force layout. I've tried adding all the variants of "keystroke", "keypress", "keyup", "keydown" that I could think of, but none of them is firing. My mouse events fire just fine. I couldn't find any keystroke events in the d3 source.... is there a way to capture key strokes?

```
        nodes.enter().append("circle")
            .on("click", function(d) { return d.clickHandler(self); })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { return d.mouseOverHandler(self); })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) { return d.mouseOutHandler(self); })
            .on("keyup", function(d) { 
                console.log("keypress", d3.event); // also tried "keyup", "keydown", "key"
            })
            .classed("qNode", true)
            .call(force.drag);
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think the problem here is you are trying to add keyboard events to elements that are not focusable, try adding a `keydown` event to a focusable element (body in this case):

```
d3.select("body")
    .on("keydown", function() { ...
```

here you can use properties of `d3.event`, for instance `d3.event.keyCode`, or for more specialized cases, `d3.event.altKey`, `d3.event.ctrlKey`, `d3.event.shiftKey`, etc..

Looking at the [KeyboardEvent Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) might be helpful as well.

I've made a simple fiddle with keyboard interaction here: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/292/

You can extend this to apply these keyboard interactions to svg elements by creating a variable to 'select' the current object:

```
var currentObject = null;
```

Then update this current object reference during appropriate mouse event methods:

```
.on("mouseover", function() {currentObject = this;})
.on("mouseout", function() {currentObject = null;});
```

Now you can use this current object in your keyboard interactions set up earlier.

here's a jsfiddle of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/295/

Comment: This works fine, but it doesn't get me at the element I want to manipulate. How do I know which SVG element was under the cursor when the keystroke event happened?

Comment: for this purpose, I would suggest adding a `mouseover` event listener on your elements, then testing for keypresses in that function, though I'm not sure this is an ideal solution

Comment: so that's getting at my question: how to I test for keypresses in a `mouseover` event without rebuilding the entire event handling infrastructure?

Comment: I've added to my answer what it seems you are getting at, consider revising the question if this is not the case

Comment: Clear answer, link to relevant docs, and live examples. Pity, I can only give you one up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tabindex attribute to the  so the element is focusable

```
svg.attr("tabindex", "0")
```