# How to listen keyboard events on svg

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js, keydown

I have a svg and I can draw multiple shapes on this svg. Now my requirement is I want to listen keyboard events like ctrl+C, ctrl+V, ctrl+D, Esc, Delete so that I can copy, paste , duplicate selected shape. But I have no idea about listening keyboard events on SVG . I tried following code but no luck !!

```
 mySVG.on("keydown", function () {
        //code to handle keydown
  });
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "no luck"?

Comment: As you stated this is D3.js-related, have a look at the following SO q&a where a possible solution is mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261447/how-do-i-capture-keystroke-events-in-d3-force-layout

Comment: No luck means , control doesn't come in handler.
SaschaM78 thanks for ur help, I dont want to listen key events on whole body , I want key events on svg only as  I have other components too in body

Comment: svg 1.1 [does not handle keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#SVGEvents) (cf.section 16.2). svg 2 [will support them](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/svgdom.html#RelationshipWithDOM3Events).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because SVG is not an input-type, listen for the event on the window instead:

```
$(window).on('keypress', function (evt){ ... })
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `tabindex="0"` attribute to the `<svg>` and it will work:

```js
const svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');

svgElement.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  console.log('svg keydown: ', event.key);
});
```

```html
<svg tabindex="0" width="300" height="200">

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555" />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
    Click me and start typing
  </text>
  
</svg>
```

> The tabindex attribute allows you to control whether an element is
> focusable, and ...

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)  for more info.

Comment: This works, thanks Darth.