# Dart SvgSvgElement does not respond to keyboard events

Tags: svg, dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

I have following code to capture onkeyPress event for the top level svg element. but system does not capture keyboard events. I can capture mouse eventrs without any problem.  HTML has following statement:

```
<svg id="mysvg" width="600" height="400">
  ...
</svg>
```

and Dart script has the following:

```
SvgSvgElement mysvg = $['mysvg'];
mysvg.onKeyPress.listen(onData);

...
onData(KeyboardEvent e) {
   print("key pressed");
}
```

The code is in a polymer component running on windows 8 platform. Dart version  1.10.0.

Is keyboard capture on svg not yet implemented in Dart? Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: for now, I just registered  a listener on window object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323977/how-to-listen-keyboard-events-on-svg