# Adding keyboard event listener to svg div container

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add keyboard even listeners (keyup, keydown) to a `<div>` that contains an `<svg>` element. [This post notes that SVGs do not currently support handling keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261447/how-do-i-capture-keystroke-events-in-d3-force-layout), so I tried adding the events to a `<div>` surrounding the `<svg>`. But it doesn't appear to work either. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xk3cwgzg/1/)) Nor does adding event handlers to a group of all the elements contained in the SVG.

Is this possible to do? Am I doing something wrong?

(I don't want to assign the event handlers to the `body` or `window` because I have a text input forms on a different part of the page.)

Answer (score 3):

you can attach keyboard event to svg elements . but along with keyboard down you have to attach focus event without attaching focus it does't works.

```
var chart = d3.select("#chart")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("height", '600px')

var svg = chart.append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 300);

var currentObject = null;

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("class","selectme").attr("id","circle")
    .attr("cx",50).attr("cy",50).attr("r",45)
    .style("fill","lightblue");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class","selectme").attr("id","rectangle")
    .attr({"x":10,"y":150,"width":150,"height":100})
    .style("fill","lightgreen");
d3.selectAll(".selectme")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke","black");
        currentObject = this;
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke","none");
        currentObject = null;
    });

d3.select("svg")
    .on("keydown", function() {
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x","5")
            .attr("y","130")
            .style("font-size","20px")
        .text("keyCode: " + d3.event.keyCode + " applied to : " + (currentObject===null ? "nothing!" : currentObject.id))  
          .transition().duration(2000)
            .style("font-size","5px")
            .style("fill-opacity",".1")
          .remove();
    }).on("focus", function(){});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working? I've tried adding focus events to the [svg](http://jsfiddle.net/xk3cwgzg/6/) and the [div](http://jsfiddle.net/xk3cwgzg/5/).

Comment: it works for me for svg yes but with div its not.  you can refer this one to make it work with div http://stackoverflow.com/a/20126915/5047556

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the SVG fiddle in my previous comment only works in Chrome, not in Firefox (49 beta). I ended up using the suggestion in the link you posted: setting a toggle using mouseover/mouseout for the SVG element, and adding the `keydown` listeners to the `window` element: `d3.select(window).on('keydown', function(){ if(toggle) keydownAction() }). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try adding the following attributes to an svg element: ".attr("focusable","true")
.attr("tabindex","0")" These allowed me to focus on different elements in an svg to hang eventListeners on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute `tabindex` with the value `0`. Example:

```
<div tabindex="0">...</div>
```

`tabindex=0` makes the div selectable so that, with a focus on it, you can catch key events.
According to the documentation, " tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation ". (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Another source of information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149416/9649530

Another solution consists in using `contenteditable="true"` but this also shows the key sequences you type in the `div`.